# How to count the number of values that are between intervals in excel

Tags: excel, intervals

## Problem

Let *v = {v1, v2, v3,.., vn}* be a set of unsorted real numbers.

I want to count to number of values vi that fall in the intervals [0,10], [20,28] etc.

---

## Example

Let `v = {2.6, 3.1, 7, 10, 22, 21, 27}`

- The number of values that fall in the interval *[0,10]* are: *2.6,3.1,7,10*
- The number of values that fall in the interval *[20, 28]* are : *22, 21 ,27*

---

I used the following formula: `=SUMPRODUCT((range>0)*(range<10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `>` and `<` to `>=` and `<=` in your SUMPRODUCT. You can also try COUNTIFS formula - should work faster. With the following sample layout:

[image]

Enter in `C3` and drag it down:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$G$1,">=" &A3,$A$1:$G$1,"<="&B3)
```

Comment: How u set the intervals is interesting that's what I also was looking for i just need then to set the intervals and copy the formula. Thank u so much